# SQL Random String from List

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I want to choose from a list of strings and assign that as the value of one of the columns for my `SELECT`.

Something like the following:

```
SELECT id, name, GET_RANDOM_TYPE('Basic', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Premium') AS type
FROM tbl
```

I'm just doing some tests hence why I need this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not terribly familiar with oracle, but perhaps you can simply use `round(dbms_random.value(1,4))` in conjunction with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,4)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Basic' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Silver' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Gold' 
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Premium' 
       END AS type
FROM table
```

Comment: Yes this works. It's the same as what Ravindra HV answered. You just happen to provide the query.

Comment: nevermind what I said about ROUND. It still needs it to work. I was using `>` or `<` so it worked on my query. Since I random from `1-10`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with your list of values that has a number as a primary key.

Then

```
Select  your_text
from your_random_table
where ID = TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,10));
```

The statement above will give you any one 10 pseudo random numbers and assumes you have 10 random values in your table.  It's not really random but works for testing. See [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to create a new table?